# PHP web socket unable to bind socket

Tags: php, apache, websocket

I have a apache server and listen to port 8000 and 80

i use below php function to create a web socket

```
private function createSocket($host,$port)
{
    if( ($this->master=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP)) < 0 )
    {
        die("socket_create() failed, reason: ".socket_strerror($this->master));
    }

    self::console("Socket {$this->master} created.");

    socket_set_option($this->master,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,1);
    #socket_set_option($master,SOL_SOCKET,SO_KEEPALIVE,1);

    if( ($ret=socket_bind($this->master,$host,$port)) < 0 )
    {
        die("socket_bind() failed, reason: ".socket_strerror($ret));
    }

    self::console("Socket bound to {$host}:{$port}.");

    if( ($ret=socket_listen($this->master,5)) < 0 )
    {
        die("socket_listen() failed, reason: ".socket_strerror($ret));
    }

    self::console('Start listening on Socket.');

    $this->allsockets[] = $this->master;
}
```

assume the $host is 127.0.0.1 and $port is 8000

when i go to shell console and start the socket server, it said Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use

when i remove the $port, it doesnt show error, but the socket server keep listening and no response

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use

This means that your server is already using the port that you selected. You'll have to choose another port until you find one that is not in use.

Comment: i try, 1234, 1235,1236,8000,8001, 8002, but same msg

Comment: Those are likely in use as well, the lower numbers are typically used first. Try ports above 40000.

Comment: try 41234, and viewed to current listen port, there is no listen state on 41234, but return the same msg, even restart server

Comment: You can easily check if a port is in use by doing `telnet 127.0.0.1 1234` for port number 1234.  If you get a connection, it's in use.

Comment: It's saying 41234 is in use too?

Comment: i got the connection , since i made Listen 41234 on httpd.conf, should i remove it?

Comment: Why are you setting apache to listen on 41234 then trying to bind your own socket to that?? That will never work. It's one socket per port.

Comment: okay , when i use a un listen port (45689), the program will hand with no error

Comment: That means it's listening and is successful.

Comment: if listen it will show self::console('Start listening on Socket.'); btw i try on other server, Thanks anyway, let me try and response u later

Comment: DOes it say that the socket was created?

Comment: Yea it created, by using other server, but other error Socket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing, anyway, the server setup is fix, million Thanks